# How do I know if ffmpeg is using a hardware decoder?

Tags: ffmpeg

I noticed when I read a video frame by frame via ffmpeg, my CPU usage explodes to 120%.

```
ffmpeg -i video.webm thumb%04d.jpg -hide_banner
```

But, if i simply watch a video locally it barely eats up any CPU.

I'm guessing the issue here is that ffmpeg isn't using my hardware decoder (on OS X no GPU). How would I even check?

Any other issue that could be occurring?

Answer (score 5):

You have to explicitly enable hardware acceleration with FFmpeg if you want to use it.  Otherwise, software codecs are used.

That is, if you don't enable hardware acceleration with flags on the command line, you can be sure that hardware acceleration isn't being used.

See also:  https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro

Comment: @farza You have some sort of GPU... probably Intel Graphics.  For that, you can use QuickSync via VAAPI.

Comment: Still doesn't explain how I can see if I'm using hardware or software decoding. ffmpeg doesn't print this info.

Comment: @danger89 Sure it does.  Did you pass a flag to use hardware decoding?  No?  Then, software is used.  It's that simple.  It only does what you tell it to do.  It doesn't make intelligent choices on its own.

Comment: `mpv` at least gives an message like this: "Using hardware decoding (vaapi).". ffmpeg doesn't give me any confirmation...

Comment: @danger89 FFmpeg is not mpv.  If you're not using hardware acceleration flags, you won't be using hardware acceleration.

Comment: I know that ffmpeg is not mpv. I said, when using mpv you get at least a confirmation that it indeed is using hardware decoding. Do you get the point? With ffmpeg I can't get any confirmation if it's successfully using a particular hardware decoding. Sure I can say `-hwaccel vaapi`, but maybe it failed somewhere and still using software?

Comment: @danger89 If `-hwaccel vaapi` fails, you'll get an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try check Intel GPU usage

```
sudo apt-get update -y

sudo apt-get install -y intel-gpu-tools

sudo intel_gpu_top
```

I believe once you set the ffmpeg param correctly, it should run in hardware acc mode.

for my case, I run frigate NVR which I cant confirm my hardware acc is running although I got set the param in yaml.